# Neo4j c# client Out of memory exception

Tags: c#, neo4j, out-of-memory, neo4jclient

I have 1+ million nodes in my neo4j database. I tried to query all of those nodes in a single query and it threw an exception due to `"Out of Memory"`.

What are best practices/how to tackle this scenario?

Basicaly how can I query a **large** dataset in neo4j from c#?

Comment: What is your hardware limitation? Have you tried to increase the amount of RAM used by the JVM?

Comment: Hey @BrunoPeres. I have left jvm/ram configs as default. I wanted to understand common patterns or what have people have done in the event that they want to query large datasets from neo4j. I could try customizing the RAM used by the JVM but sounds like a "hack"...? what if tomorrow I have 10 million nodes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments:

> Hey @BrunoPeres. I have left jvm/ram configs as default. I wanted to
>   understand common patterns or what have people have done in the event
>   that they want to query large datasets from neo4j.

If you really want to work with the 1+ million nodes at same time I believe is nothing to do... You will need increase your available hardware. Otherwise you can use SKIP and LIMIT to do some pagination-like approach.

> I could try customizing the RAM used by the JVM but sounds like a "hack"...? what if tomorrow I have 10 million nodes..

Well, if your amount of nodes has increased from 1 million to 10 million this means that your hardware requirements has increased too.

Comment: Thanks that is reasonable. Do you have a snippet of code or some doc I can reference to for the SKIP? I have already tested queries with LIMIT but if I want to do  a proper pagination I would have to use skip. DO you happen to know how using the neo4j c# client?

Comment: @KevinCohen according [this test file](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/blob/d1c2fd11faf9ff17f8cc5f7b9506a647e0d414fb/Neo4jClient.Tests/Cypher/CypherFluentQuerySkipTests.cs#L20) from neo4jclient library the `Skip`method should be called after the `Return` passing a integer as parameter.

Comment: Yep, can confirm it works. I did .Return().Skip(skipCount).Limit(10000).Results.ToList(); and inside a while loop so that periodically queries neo4j